# For loop skip the instance

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Description: In for loop 48 and 4 not removing, when i debug that code i find for loop skip that don't even check the condition.

skip the instance.

Code:

```
my_list = [12, 25, 36, 48, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 13, 22, 19]

for num in my_list:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        my_list.remove(num)

print(my_list)
```

Output: [25, 48, 3, 5, 7, 4, 13, 19]

Expected output: [25, 3, 5, 7, 13, 19]

Comment: It's never recommend way to *remove* items while looping the *list* - because the *index* will be off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `remove`, you are changing `my_list` and iterating on it at the same time. So iteration won't work as you expect. The easier way can be this:

```py
my_list = [12, 25, 36, 48, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 13, 22, 19]
new_list = []

for num in my_list:
    if num % 2 != 0:
        new_list.append(num)

print(new_list)
```